# PHP Array combine using one column value

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to combine two Arrays with one common column.But, not getting exactly what I want. Please check the below requirement.

**Array 1**

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fieldLabel] => fname
        [uuid] => 27478
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fieldLabel] => Lname
        [uuid] => 6103
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fieldLabel] => Country
        [uuid] => 7350
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fieldLabel] => check1
        [uuid] => 23155
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fieldLabel] => radio1
        [uuid] => 15664
    )

  )
```

**Array 2**

```
 Array
 (
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [uuid] => 27478
        [value] => sai1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [uuid] => 6103
        [value] => sai2
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [uuid] => 7350
        [value] => USA
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [uuid] => 23155
        [value] => USA|India
    )

  )
```

I need output like the below. Both arrays 'UUID' is common.  If value not there in second array it should be empty.

Array
    (
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fieldLabel] => fname
            [uuid] => 27478
            [value] =>sai1
        )

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fieldLabel] => Lname
        [uuid] => 6103
        [value] =>sai2
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fieldLabel] => Country
        [uuid] => 7350
        [value] =>USA
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fieldLabel] => check1
        [uuid] => 23155
        [value] =>USA|India
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fieldLabel] => radio1
        [uuid] => 15664
    )

  )
```

Please provide your suggestions. How can I achieve.

Comment: Please, share what you already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse those arrays and make changes like below :

```
foreach ($array1 as &$a1val) {
   $value = 0;
   foreach ($array2 as $a2val) {
      if($a1val->uuid == $a2val->uuid) {
          $value = $a2val->value;
          break; 
      }
   }
   $a1val->value = $value;
}
```

P.S. :

1. & is used to update $array1 by reference.

Comment: Thanks for your response. its working fine. I added small code.. i.e. if(isset($a1val->uuid))... I am getting error without that validation..

Comment: Glad to be of any help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach($arr1 as $key1 => val1){
            foreach($arr2 as $key2 => $val2){
                if($val1['uuid'] ==  $val2['uuid']){
                    $arr1[$key1]['value'] = $val2['value'];
                }
            }
       }
print_r($arr1); // this should give desire output
```